# How to compare two mathml values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mathml

I have an html page which has a math question and mathml(to display formulas in browser) as options.So when user selects the option, need to compare the selected option with correct answer. Whereas the option value is a mathml. So how to compare two mathml values using java script ?

P.S should not use any external libraries.

Comment: What is a "MathML value" exactly? How are you working with the MathML DOM from Javascript? Please share your code.

Comment: What is your definition of compare? Equal and not equal? Your question needs a lot more detail with example inputs and expected results. Also, you have to try something, and then ask why it isn't working, Stack Overflow is for questions on code you are stuck on, not code you have no clue how to start.

Comment: Juan, I wanted to check if value selected by user is equal to the correct answer. And i had triedand was stuck ,since i am new to Mathml i had this question. And there is no reason to be rude !!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have MathML with formulas involving some variables like x+1 or sqrt(a^2+b^2). In this case, you will need a CAS (Computer Algebra System) to do the evaluation of the answer.

I do not know how to do that without using a library, call it external or not, except evaluating the formula at a given set of points and check that both the correct answer and the student answer give the same values; although this method might fail in some circumstances. That’s why I suggest using a CAS.

The CAS can be written in JavaScript or in any other language which is the most common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to compare two MathML expressions
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dl-mathml-compare

1. Install via `npm install dl-mathml-compare`
2. Require in your code using `var DLMathMLCompare = require('dl-mathml-compare');`
3. Use in your code as `DLMathMLCompare('Your MathML expression here', 'Your another MathML expression');`
4. It will return `true` if matched otherwise returns `false`

**Example:**

```
DLMathMLCompare('<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mrow><mn>2</mn><msqrt><mo>&#xA0;</mo></msqrt><mo>&#xA0;</mo></mrow></mfrac></math>', '<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mrow><mn>2</mn><msqrt/><mo>&#xA0;</mo></mrow></mfrac><mo>&#xA0;</mo><mo>&#xA0;</mo> </math> ')
// This will return true
```